# Blender export.FBX "action" attribute is read only?

Tags: animation, export, unity, .fbx

I'm trying to export my model and armature with the several animations I made to Unity but for some reason I'm getting an error I never got before.

All of my animations are on the armature, not on the mesh.

I click export in .FBX, then select armature and mesh but I get the error "action" attribute in AnimData is read-only. I can export only the mesh to Unity without problems (but then of course i have no skeleton and no animations so the problem has to come from the armature).

Does anyone know why that happens and how I can fix it please ?